# Very slow UPDATE with PutDatabaseRecord processor

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi

I have 2 `PutDatabaseRecord` which are writing to `Oracle DB`.

This is part of the schema:

[image: Schema]

The red square there ins't error, but information messages, thus I put the processor to INFO mode. So it tells about fetching the schema, and "Commit because of batch size" with SQL update command.

The problem is, that first of them: `ml_task`, processes several millions records in few minutes, but the other one: `ml_sales` - stack with 1000 records several hours... This stacks both at night, when DB is much loaded and at a day time.

In a same moment, `update goods.ml_[name] set load_date = sysdate` statements takes same time via the SQLDeveloper interface - both for `ml_task` and `ml_sales`. It takes around of 10 minutes as night and several minutes at a day.

Both of them working with same pooling service.

This is the configuration of the bottom part of the service:

[image: Pooling config]

Both of the processors have same configuration, except the table name and update keys.

[image: Processors' config]

I tried set `Max Batch Size` to zero, it have no influence.

Both of the processors configured run in one thread,but I tried to configure 10 threads - there is no influence.

Also, there isn't lack of connections to the DB at all, I have around of 10 processors, every one uses one thread, so 50 connections, I think is enough.

There are around 5 millions record they are processing.

This is JSON of `ml_task`:

```
[{"DOC_ID": 1799041400,"LINE_D":694098344,"LOAD_DATE":"16-Jul-21"} ... ]
```

This is something similar to Nifi's update for `ml_task`:

```
update goods.ml_task
set load_date = sysdate
where doc_id = ? 
and line_id = ?;
```

This is the table:

```
Name          Null?    Type   
------------- -------- ------ 
DOC_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER 
LINE_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER 
ORG_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER 
NMCL_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER 
ASSORTMENT_ID NOT NULL NUMBER 
START_DATE    NOT NULL DATE   
END_DATE               DATE   
ITEMS_QNT              NUMBER 
MODIFY_DATE            DATE   
LOAD_DATE              DATE
```

This is a JSON of `ml_sales`:

```
[{"REP_DATE":"06-Jul-21","NMCL_ID":336793,"ASSORT_ID":7,"RTT_ID":92,"LOAD_DATE":"16-Jul-21"} ... ]
```

Request for `ml_sales` is such as:

```
update goods.ml_sales set load_date = sysdate
where nmcl_id = ?
and assort_id = ?
and rtt_id = ?
and rep_date = ?;
```

And the table:

```
Name        Null?    Type       
----------- -------- ---------- 
REP_DATE    NOT NULL DATE       
NMCL_ID     NOT NULL NUMBER(38) 
ASSORT_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER     
RTT_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(38) 
OUT_ITEMS            NUMBER     
MODIFY_DATE          DATE       
LOAD_DATE            DATE
```

What can be reason for so slow update of `ml_sales`?

**UPDATE**

I put all the circuits to `STOP` except the problematic one, I committed all sessions in `SQLDeveloper`... and it is the same result... very long...

**UPDATE**

As I mentioned above, I actually copied the `ml_sales` table to other scheme and this didn't influenced the result.

Comment: As a test, can you please copy that ml_sales table to, let's say ml_sales2 and run that process against it?  How long will it take to update?

Comment: You have 1 thread sequentially writing 5m records...that's going to be quite slow. NiFi is designed for parallelism - increase the amount of the nodes & threads that are writing to the DB in parallel. If increasing the amount of amount of concurrent tasks isn't making a difference - is it actually spawning multuple threads? Is the node over-utilised? Is the DB over-utilised?

Comment: ekochergin - I did it, I copied the table to my schema, it wasn't increase the speed.

Comment: Sdairs, I will do it, but now I try to fetch just several thousands of records, and I stopped all the Nifi except the problematic flow.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns that are in your where clauses?

Comment: I guess there were not indexes. I asked our DBA's to check the problem in DB side, they fixed it, but I still don't know what was the problem, so very possible, that it were indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there were problem in lack of indexes in Oracle. I asked our DBA's to check the problem in DB side, they fixed it, now the `UPDATE` works as fast as for `ml_task` table, but unfortunately I still don't know what exactly was the problem, thus out DBA left for vocation. So, again, very possible that it were indexes problem.